# xsd:unique with optional attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, unique

I have this Xml file:

```
<objects>
  <object name="ID1" />
  <object name="ID2" />
  <object name="ID2" color="green" />
  <object name="ID3" color="green" />
<objects>
```

I would like to validate this against an XSD Schema, so that the combination between `name` and `color` are unique in the document.

The problem is that, if I use:

```
<xs:unique name="UniqueObjectNameColor">
  <xs:selector xpath="./object" />
  <xs:field xpath="@name" />
  <xs:field xpath="@color" />
</xs:unique>
```

... the rule will ignore `object` elements without the optional `color` attribute. The following validates correctly while it shouldn't.

```
  <object name="ID2" />
  <object name="ID2" />
```

Can you tell me how can I specify a rule that enforces unique `name` and `color` combinations and, when the `color` attribute is not present in the element `object`, it checks the `name`?

Comment: I'd like to know the same thing. The answer form micfra doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: It may break your schema, but does setting a default value for the color attribute help?  e.g. <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string" default=""/>

Comment: @MattyK that fixed this issue for me. Thanks very much!

Comment: @MattyK That seems to work, but only when default is not an empty string but something different. Still seems like a strange workaround to me unfortunately, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

Use `use` and `default` with or without a value like:

```
    <element name="objects">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="object" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <complexType>
                        <attribute name="name" type="string" />
                        <attribute name="color" type="string" use="optional" default="noColor" />
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <unique name="UniqueObjectNameColor">
            <selector xpath="tns:object" />
            <field xpath="@name" />
            <field xpath="@color" />
        </unique>
    </element>

</schema>
```

Comment: Note that this only works when using .NET's XDocument.Validate if you pass in true for the optional addSchemaInfo argument.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but worth to be answered. You can use more than one `unique` constraint per element. This would do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/xsdunique-with-optional-properties"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/xsdunique-with-optional-properties"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <element name="objects">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="object" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <complexType>
                        <attribute name="name" type="string" />
                        <attribute name="color" type="string" />
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <unique name="UniqueObjectName">
            <selector xpath="tns:object" />
            <field xpath="@name" />
        </unique>
        <unique name="UniqueObjectNameColor">
            <selector xpath="tns:object" />
            <field xpath="@name" />
            <field xpath="@color" />
        </unique>
    </element>

</schema>
```

Comment: Hi micfra, thanks for your reply.
I want this to be valid:
`<object name="ID2" /><object name="ID2" color="green" />`
With your 'UniqueObjectName' constraint this won't be valid.
I only wanted to avoid exact copies:
Not valid:
`<object name="ID2" /><object name="ID2" />`
Not valid:
`<object name="ID2" color="green" /><object name="ID2" color="green" />`

Comment: So I did not understood your question correct, but it may be achievable.

Comment: If you have the possibility to change to XMl Schema 1.1, you can add <assert test=".."/> on your "object" definition. I'm not familiar with this, so I can't help you any further.